# java JTable - инфа в таблице не видна до клика мышкой по ней

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Сделал таблицу JTable, по ходу выполнения программы она успешно заполняется, но пока не кликнешь на строке - она выглядит пустой.

```
private static String[][] tableData = new String[1000][3];
private static String[] tableHeaders = {"...", "..." , "..."};
```

Создание таблицы:

```
private void createUIComponents() {
    reportTable = new JTable(tableData, tableHeaders);
    reportTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

}
```

Есть еще `addListSelectionListener`, но он вроде работает норм и с самой таблицей ничего не делает, так что проблема не из-за него.

Добавление `reportTable.setVisible(true);` не помогло.

==============================================

UPD: Добавляю больше информации.

Как все работает:

1. По нажатию кнопки создается информация для заполнения. Там все норм, т.к. инфа еще экспортируется в виде файла html и в нем все нормально + выводиться лог что все заполнено.
2. По нажатию другой кнопки начинается заполнение таблички методом `frameReport`. Это просто перенос инфы из рабочего `ArrayList<User> interestUsers` в `String[][] tableData`, который собственно и передается для создания JTable.
3. В табличке есть еще листенер, который при нажатии на строку выводит рядом в JLabel более подробную инфу по этой строке.

Листенер, который активирует заполнение таблицы через метод `frameReport`

```
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


   Main.setInterestUsers(Search.filterBySubscribes(Main.getFilteredUsers()));

            frameReport(Main.interestUsers);
        }

    });
```

Метод `frameReport(Main.interestUsers)`

```
public void frameReport(ArrayList<User> interestUsers){



    for (int i = 0; i < interestUsers.size(); i++) {
        tableData[i][0] = interestUsers.get(i).getFirst_name() + " " + interestUsers.get(i).getLast_name();
        tableData[i][1] = "..." + interestUsers.get(i).getId();
        tableData[i][2] = printGroups(interestUsers.get(i).getInterestGroups());

    }

}
```

Создание таблицы и листенер, реагирующий на выделение строки:

```
private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
        reportTable = new JTable(tableData, tableHeaders);
        reportTable
                   .getSelectionModel()
                   .setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 
        imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon());

        reportTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new 
ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                /*
                    действия при выделении столбца
                */

                // set img
                imgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.getInterestUsers().get(reportTable.getSelectedRow()).getPhotoPath()));
                // set info
                infoTextArea.append("Info... TODO \n");

            }
        });
    }
```

Скриншот: сразу после выделения одной строки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, чтоб понимать что происходит в целом

Comment: Приведенного кода недостаточно, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Создайте [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: вы заполняете таблицу в правильном потоке?

Comment: Добавил больше инфы. Насчет правильного потока - у меня однопоточное приложение.